# При наличии компонента на странице, содержимое ВСЕЙ страницы выводится только для админов на Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Знатоки, нужен хелп, не понимаю каким образом, но при наличии компонента на странице Bitrix содержимое всей страницы выводится только для админов и всё работает корректно. При этом для неавторизованных пользователей выводится только Шапка и Футер. Если вывод компонента вырезать из кода, то всё выводится норм (но соответвенно без нужного компонента). Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Вывод компонента:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "index-proiz",
    Array(
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "index-proiz",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FIELD_CODE" => array(0=>"NAME",1=>"PREVIEW_PICTURE",2=>"",),
        "FILTER_NAME" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "27",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "news",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".index-proiz",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Примеры исполнения лазерной резки",
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "N",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "N",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N"
    )
);?>
```

ШАблон компонента:

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */

use Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;

$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.another_project .slider').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        navSpeed: 750,
        smartSpeed: 750,
        autoplaySpeed: 750,
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 10000,
        responsive : {
            700 : {
                items: 4
            },
            300 : {
                items: 2,
                margin:20
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
<?if(!empty($arResult["ITEMS"])):?>
<div class="cont lazer_slider_block">
    <section class="another_project">
    <div class="block_h1"><span></span><h2>Примеры исполнения лазерной резки</h2><span></span></div>

        <article class="news owl-carousel slider owl-theme">
            <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] AS $obItem):?>
                <?
                $this->AddEditAction($obItem['ID'], $obItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($obItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
                $this->AddDeleteAction($obItem['ID'], $obItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($obItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), Array("CONFIRM" => Loc::getMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
                ?>

<div id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($obItem['ID']);?>" class="slide project_itm">
            <a>
                <div class="article-item">
                    <div class="article-content_wrapper">
                        <?if(!empty($obItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
                            <div class="article-content_img">
                                <img src="<?=$obItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]['MINI']['src'];?>" alt="<?=$obItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]['ALT'];?>" />
                            </div>
                        <?endif;?>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
            <?endforeach;?>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
<?endif;?>
```

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, вывод компонента всем оставшимся кодом, который у Вас указан в файле

Comment: Пробовали чистить кэш через кнопку "Сбросить кэш" верней панели? Либо можно в панели Администратора в разделе "Автокэширования" выбрать "Очистка файлов кэша". Попробуйте очистить всё.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Вопрос решился. Проблема была в правах доступа самого компонента. До этого указывал доступы, но был супер-кеш)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо! Вопрос решился. Проблема была в правах доступа самого компонента. До этого указывал доступы, но был супер-кеш)